# Copy CSVReader output to array (single index to new array)

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file which i am reading with the CSVReader library.

I want to iterate through the file row by row and save the values from a particular column to a new Array.

The following code gives me a list of data from the 2nd column.

How do i take this data and save it to an array?
I am specifying the column delimiter as a comma and skipping the first two lines of the file

```
public class ReadFile {


        // Location of file to read

    private static final String FILE="myfile.csv"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FILE), ',','\'', 2);

            String [] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

                   System.out.println(nextLine[1]);
        }
           }
    }
```

Current output from nextLine[1]

```
1720178147618
1720178147617
1720178147616
1720178147615
1720178147614
1720178147613
1720178147612
```

Desired output

```
String[] ID = 1720178147618, 1720178147617, 1720178147616, 1720178147615, 1720178147614, 1720178147613, 1720178147612
```

I think what im after is instructions on how to convert data stored in single index, to a new Array of separate indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the content to a `List` - this is an extensible collection structure,

```
final List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

And in your code

```
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    list.add(nextLine[1]);
}
```

Then, if you want an `String[]` you can call the `toArray` method

```
final String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

But you could also just use the `List`.

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks! Appreciate the help from everyone who replied.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `CSVReader` from the [Open CSV library](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), the [documentation](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html) shows that there is a method `readAll()` that will do exactly what you're looking to do:

`List<String[]> values = reader.readAll();`

Comment: Hi chrisn, thanks for the response. I tried readAll(), however it reads the entire CSV file, im after just one column. Even if i do use readAll() how would i go about saving the output of the list to an array? I tried the list .toArray function and  i was able to get one value but can't work out how to iterate through to obtain all of the rows

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were looking to achieve. Glad someone else was able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Given the other answer, I'm not sure this is what you're looking for anymore. I understood it as you wanted a single array containing only the 2nd column data?

Here's what I have:

```
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    while...{
        strings.add( nextLine[1] );
    }
    String[] ID = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
```

Though, you could also use chrisn's answer and just do:

```
String[] ID = values.get(1);
```